# PDF core (Type1) fonts download?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, download, standards

When I wrote my PDF creation program I used the AFM files from the Adobe homepage to have the font metrics of the 14 core fonts.

Now I try rendering of simple PDFs, but I need the font files for the 14 core fonts to render correctly or to convert PDFs to PDF/As.

Any idea where to get them?

Comment: Any Acrobat reader should have them installed. Adobe/Reader9.0/Resource/Font.

Comment: Even if Adobe Reader does have them installed doesn't mean you can use them in another installation. And at least on Mac OS X Reader *does not* have those fonts installed (they have some of them and some come close but it's far from a good set of the core 14 fonts).

Comment: What made you believe these *copyrighted* fonts can be (legally) downloaded anywhere? Isn't that the reason that GhostScript comes with clones (albeit metrics compatible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have searched the StackOverflow website like this:

- **https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2214+fonts%22**

The top question turning up there features two answers with more than 1 upvote. These may help with your current question too.

Comment: why post this as answer instead of voting to close as duplicate?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I follow my (private) policy to avoid any actions which may discourage newbie SO users to come back...

Comment: that's why you also leave a comment to explain why.  The closing as duplicate benefits everyone on the internet hitting Stackoverflow in the future, and the separate comment benefits the person asking the question right now - everyone wins =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I disagree. Many comments "explaining why" just don't cut it (or are simply way off). Even if they match 100%, they still discourage...

Comment: that's your choice, just be aware that you're not not quite acting in line with the official (insomuch as there can be one) policy as detailed over at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled (which prefers people to comment, not answer, unless it's an *actual* answer)

Comment: It's ***very much*** in line with the *"It depends"* tagged actions. It does NOT categorically say to "not answer". Also, it's not exactly a duplicate question! Finally: at least I hinted the OP how he can search the SO site. Thanks for trying to teach me about SO policies.